# Localize 2D Image In 3D Point Cloud

Tags: computer-vision, localization, point-clouds, photogrammetry

Given an RGB point cloud of a scene and 2D image of some place within that scene. Is there a way of determining the location of the image within the point cloud? possibly the camera position as well?

*I have thought about matching SIFT key-points, but that works between images only.*

Comment: Do you mean you want to do something like matching a point cloud of Times Square and a photo taken at Times Square?

Comment: Yes, exactly @Guang

Comment: It is not easy. Most straight forward way (but not practical) is to generate many many "snapshots" of the 3D point cloud, then try to see which one matches the input photo the best, but the search space is huge, so not practical; If you could segment the 3D clouds into different objects or color patches, and also segment the 2D photo into objects/color patches, that might reduce the search space; If you could recognize objects in the 2D photo (a blue car, a person in red), and also label the objects in the 3D clouds, then the search space would be even smaller.

Comment: store feature descriptors with your point cloud, as you generate it... if you generate it from pictures.